# Problem when saving a txt file in python (name of the file with some capital letters)?

Tags: python, numpy, uppercase

I am trying to save a txt file, as follows "pix_1_WND.txt" but save it as "pix_1_wnd.txt"

The code I am using is:

```
np.savetxt(out_DS1+'pix_'+str(c)+'_'+'WND.txt',type1, fmt='%s')
```

Thank you.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using win10

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I was trying to save two txt files in the same folder, for some reason I wrote about the txt I had created before.
Then, save the first one in a different folder from the second one.
The difference between the two txt is the variable that I am saving in capital letters.

Thanks :D